# JSON Reads/Writes/Format Combinators Play - Use different key name while creating json

Tags: json, scala, playframework

I have following json:

```
{
"key_as_string":"StringOne",
"doc_count":1
}
```

How should I create a Play Scala Read combinators by using JsonParse as case class object.

```
case class JsonParse(key:String,doc_count:Long)

implicit val placeReads: Reads[JsonParse] = (
      (JsPath \ "key_as_string").read[String] and
        (JsPath \ "doc_count").read[Long]
      )(JsonParse.apply _)
```

I want to map "key_as_string" which is present in json to "key" which is present in the case class

```
JsonParse(key = "StringOne",doc_count = 1)
```

Comment: what's your problem here?

Comment: @AlixB While parsing the json - the "key_as_string" data will be stored in "key_as_string" variable of the case class object. How should i map and store in the variable called key.
I hope I am making it clear.

Comment: The `apply _` gives you a `f: (string, long) => JsonParse` and you're calling it with String, Long, so I can't see what's bothering you here. Your code seems right to me, do you have any compile error or runtime error?

Comment: I was under the impression that the object name should match with the key. I realized a lil late.Thanks @AlixB

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have works fine. As long as the json key specified in the `JsPath` matches the actual json schema -- it does in your snippet -- you're free to name the case class param whatever you'd like.

Comment: Thanks. I realized this lil late